# Is retained mode data stored on the GPU?

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx

So I've been through lists of questions about retained vs immediate mode rendering, but no one seems to specify whether the scene data stored by the graphics API (OpenGL/DirectX) is stored into RAM or onto the GPU's memory. Common sense tells me that the API will store scene data onto the GPU for you, but nothing I've seen online directly specified this. Is this because it depends on settings within the API?

Just to be clear, my question is the following: In retained mode graphics, is the scene data always stored into the GPU's memory, or does it depend on certain settings within the graphics API?

Comment: It definitely depends on the API. As far as I understand there is not even a guarantee that any of the retained mode APIs uses a GPU for drawing at all.

Comment: So, by **default** in modern OpenGL, if there is a GPU present, does OpenGL store all scene data on the GPU always? (In retained mode of course, since immediate mode isn't present in newer versions)

Comment: It might store it in GPU memory. Unless the implementation decides that it better to store it in CPU memory (for example when data is mapped into CPU memory or when GPU memory is simply full).

Comment: Alright, thanks a ton BDL! I can't upvote your comment or mark it as the best answer, but I hope my sincere appreciation counts instead :)

Comment: Paritosh answer is already very good. I'd say 99.9%. You should select that one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern OpenGL .You store your data like vertices in some array that array is stored in CPU memory (RAM) . When I do some this like this

```
void* memory = glMapBuffer(...);
```

This returns me handle to memory in device driver area.
So you copy your data directly to device driver memory and you can avoid local copy of data.
Later on device driver will move this data to graphics memory. 
Depending upon your settings like `GL_STATIC_DRAW`, `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` device driver decide which memory (GPU or CPU) should be selected and how data should be aligned for optimal access. 
So some what Immediate mode does this (OpenGL)

If you see old versions of OpenGL had something called as display list.
Where you write geometry once and compile it into display list and whenever you want to draw just use precompiled code. So some what retained functionality was there.

In pure retained mode API`s like WPF all the major workload like initialization , life cycle management is done by API so you have very little control over this tweaking and hence it depends on API there where it puts data for optimized access.

Comment: I didnot say GPU memory. If you read carefully I am mentioning driver memory. When driver moves it to GPU is implementation dependent and not by OpenGL thats for sure. But getting things directly in driver memory is still one step of optimization.